# Is it possible to update the type of property in Apache AGE?

Tags: apache-age, opencypher

Suppose I have an Apache AGE graph database `'books'` in which some vertices have the `pages` property stored in different types, as shown in the examples below:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('books', $$      
CREATE (v:Book {title: 'A book', pages: 10})
RETURN v $$) as (v agtype);
                                                v                                                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Book", "properties": {"pages": 10, "title": "A book"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('books', $$
CREATE (v:Book {title: 'Another book', pages: '10'})
RETURN v $$) as (v agtype);
                                                    v                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Book", "properties": {"pages": "10", "title": "Another book"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to update all occurrences of `pages` of type string to type integer? In other words, is there a way to update the type of all properties  of a particular type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to change the data type of property values for vertices and edges.

**Integer To String:**

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('books', $$
  MATCH (v:Book) 
  SET v.pages = tostring(v.pages)
  RETURN v
$$) AS (res agtype);
                                                res                             
                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Book", "properties": {"pages": "10", "title": "A book"}}::vertex
```

**String To Integer:**

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('books', $$
  MATCH (v:Book) 
  SET v.pages = (v.pages)::integer
  RETURN n
$$) AS (res agtype);
                                                res                             
                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Book", "properties": {"pages": 10, "title": "A book"}}::vertex
(1 row)
```

You can use typecasting for converting one data type to other using `::` operator.

Make sure you use `(v.pages)::int` rather than `v.pages::int` to avoid unexpected results because the `::` has more precedence than `.` operator

Answer (score 0):

- You can use **typecasting** to convert one data type to another using the `::` operator.

  ```
  SELECT * FROM cypher ('books', 
  $$
    MATCH (v:Book)
    SET v.pages = (v.pages)::integer
    RETURN v
  $$
  ) AS (res agtype);
  ```

**Note:** Try to use `(v.pages)::int` rather than `v.pages::int` to avoid unexpected results because the `::` operator has higher precedence than the `.` operator.